# Python's mmap() performance down with time

Tags: python, performance, memory, mmap

I am wondering why Python's *mmap()* performance going down with time? I mean I have a little app which make changes to N files, if set is big *(not too really big, say 1000)* first 200 is demon-speed but after that it goes slower and slower. It looks like I should free memory once in a while but don't know how and most importantly why Python do not do this automagically.

Any help?

-- edit --

It's something like that:

```
def function(filename, N):
   fd = open(filename, 'rb+')
   size = os.path.getsize(filename)
   mapped = mmap(fd.fileno(), size)

   for i in range(N):
      some_operations_on_mmaped_block()

   mapped.close()
```

Comment: Can we see some code? That might show a reason why GC isn't working.

Comment: Added code, it's actually almost everything, inside the loop I make 3 operations on file IF the statement is true.

Comment: Have you actually watched `top` or the Task Manager or whatever for your platform? Is Python taking up more and more memory? Is the CPU pegged? Or is it just your hard drive cache filling up?

Comment: When it's running slow, have you looked at the OS stats? Wondering if you are swapping. That would indicate a gc issue.

Does setting mapped to `null` improve or fix your issue?

Answer (score 6):

Your OS caches the mmap'd pages in RAM. Reads and writes go at RAM speed from the cache. Dirty pages are eventually flushed. On Linux performance will be great until you have to start flushing pages, this is controlled by vm.dirty_ratio sysctl variable. Once your start flushing dirty pages to disk the reads will compete with the writes on your busy IO bus/device. Another thing to consider is simply whether your OS has enough RAM to cache all the files (the buffers counter in top output). So I would watch the output of "vmstat 1" while your program runs and watch the cache / buff counters go up until suddenly you start doing IO.